# How i can use min and max CSS functions to work with auto

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I want to be able to use the common `margin: auto` property, but with a minimum margin, such as:

```
margin: 0 max(auto, 16px);
```

This would center an element horizontally & still enforce 16px of margin on either side when the viewport is too small. but not worked `min()` and `max()` CSS with `margin: auto;`

for example:
I want to set style `margin-left: 30px;` and `margin-right: 30px;` for `.navbar__menu` when screen lower 500px. **(without use @media query)**

```css
.navbar__menu {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar__menu">

</div>
```

Comment: share your full code so we can see the nature of the element you want to center

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `margin-inline: max(30px,50% - 500px/2)` and no need to set a `max-width` (more detail: https://css-tip.com/center-max-width/)

```css
.navbar__menu {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-inline: max(30px,50% - 500px/2);
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar__menu">

</div>
```

Comment: Nice. FYI this fails to center the element if there is also a min-width that is larger than the implicit maximum width (500px). Whilst in theory setting a min-width that exceeds the maximum would be a bug in the stylesheet, that kind of thing can happen easily due to cascading style overrides.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't bother inspecting the code too much, but for me, in a `block` element, it worked well enough to set just a `padding-inline` as the minimum "margin" in conjunction with `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`. Ok, the minimum is not really a margin, but the effect is the same if in the element you didn't have any previous padding: it wont add up to the empty space you will get on both sides when centered.

I use this in conjunction with a `width: min-content` and works perfectly when dealing with an inner table that can grow wider than the available screen space, allowing this minimum empty space on smaller screens and without having to worry with fixed screen resolutions neither `max()`, `min()` or other CSS calculations.

Have to aknowledge user Temani Afif because he gave me the inspiration for my solution after reading his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `max-width`:
**Update**: I saw in Temani Afif's answer the advice not to use max-width, but I think it's appropriate.

```css
.navbar__menu {
  --offset: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: calc(100% - var(--offset) * 2);
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar__menu"></div>
```

---

*P.S. 1 line solution:*

```css
.navbar__menu {
  width: min(500px, calc(100% - 30px * 2));
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar__menu"></div>
```

Comment: I never advice to not use max-width. I simply provided a solution where you don't need to use max-width. 1 line of code instead of 3.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok, thanks, I understand you. Actually, 3 lines for clarity. Added a one-line solution to the answer.

Comment: That's 2 lines ;) (I wasn't counting the CSS variable). margin: auto is part of the solution.